# Заглавные символы в URL. Как исправить?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Столкнулся с задачей: "пофиксить заглавные символы в URL". Сейчас на сайте вполне возможно указать URL в котором будут присутствовать заглавные буквы:
`site.com/blog-ARTICLE-1`

Из-за этого могут получиться дубли страниц, поэтому нужно исправить проблему. Посмотрел, что поэтому поводу говорит гугл - все сводиться корректировки .htaccess (или настройки виртуального хоста + .htaccess).

Сводиться к тому, что если указана(-ы) заглавные буквы - происходит редирект на главную. Но у меня стойкое чувство - что это не то, что надо :)

Покопавшись заметил, что указать произвольный регистр можно только у `slug`. Он находиться в БД и у данного поля выставлен collation: "utf8mb4_ci", т.е. регистро-независимый и именно поэтому, можно спокойно обратиться по двум урл:

1. site.com/blog-ARTICLE-1
2. site.com/blog-article-1

Работаю с Symfony(версия 4.3.11) не так давно, поэтому сходу не могу нагуглить. Есть ли возможность в Doctrine указать collate регистро-зависимый? Что бы по первому адресу появлялась 404? Через аннотацию или любым другим способом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно пойти несколькими путями:

1. смена collate в файле `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`
2. установка `beberlei/doctrineextensions` и последующее использование функции в самих запросах репозитория
3. можно пойти другим путём, создать листенер, который будет приводить url в нижний регистр и делать 301й редирект, таким образом, поисковики больше не будут индексировать страницы с урлом верхнего регистра

ну и примерный код листенера

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use function preg_match;
use function strtolower;

class JsonHttpListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest'],
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $pathInfo = $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo();

        if (empty($pathInfo)) {
            return;
        }

        if (0 < preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', $pathInfo)) {
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(strtolower($pathInfo), Response::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY));
        }
    }
}
```